# Isn't VBA Shell supposed to be asynchronous?

Tags: vba

When I call a rebol script with

```
call shell("rebol.exe myscript.r")
```

The shell doesn't return until the script is finished. Is there a way to force VBA Shell to be asynchronous ?

Comment: VBA Shell *is* asynchronous. Please provide more details, what's the application, its version, how the code is called etc.

Comment: Yes I know it is that's why I'm surprised that in the above case it doesn't behave as expected. 

How the code is given above and I use a button click to do so in ms access 2007.

Maybe there's something specific to rebol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to use `Shell` function, try another option with using API :

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
  (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
  ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
  ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
```

This is the full code of `ShellEx` function  :

http://www.vbaccelerator.com/codelib/shell/shellex.htm

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to pass in a second argument to make the program run in the background.  [Here's the documentation](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/9/shell-and-shellexecute-function/).

```
call shell("rebol.exe myscript.r", vbMinimizedNoFocus)
```

Comment: Well I just tried it didn't work. And when I read doc it's about setting focus not really about being asynchronous.